# How to manage memory while reading CSV using Apache Arrow C++ API?

Tags: c++, csv, apache-arrow

I don't understand memory management in C++ Arrow API. I use Arrow 1.0.0 and I'm reading CSV file. After a few runs of `ReadArrowTableFromCSV`, my memory is full of allocated data. Am I missing something? How can I free that memory? I don't see any method in memory pool to clear all allocated memory. Code Listing below.

```
void LoadCSVData::ReadArrowTableFromCSV( const std::string & filePath )
{
    auto tableReader = CreateTableReader( filePath );
    ReadArrowTableUsingReader( *tableReader );
}

std::shared_ptr<arrow::csv::TableReader> LoadCSVData::CreateTableReader( const std::string & filePath )
{
    arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
    auto tableReader = arrow::csv::TableReader::Make( pool, OpenCSVFile( filePath ),
                                                      *PrepareReadOptions(), *PrepareParseOptions(), *PrepareConvertOptions() );
    if ( !tableReader.ok() )
    {
        throw BadParametersException( std::string( "CSV file reader error: " ) + tableReader.status().ToString() );
    }
    return *tableReader;
}

void LoadCSVData::ReadArrowTableUsingReader( arrow::csv::TableReader & reader )
{
    auto table = reader.Read();
    if ( !table.ok() )
    {
        throw BadParametersException( std::string( "CSV file reader error: " ) + table.status().ToString() );
    }
    this->mArrowTable = *table;
}

std::unique_ptr<arrow::csv::ParseOptions> LoadCSVData::PrepareParseOptions()
{
    auto parseOptions = std::make_unique<arrow::csv::ParseOptions>( arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults() );
    parseOptions->delimiter = mDelimiter;
    return parseOptions;
}

std::unique_ptr<arrow::csv::ReadOptions> LoadCSVData::PrepareReadOptions()
{
    auto readOptions = std::make_unique<arrow::csv::ReadOptions>( arrow::csv::ReadOptions::Defaults() );
    readOptions->skip_rows = mNumberOfHeaderRows;
    readOptions->block_size = 1 << 27;  // 128 MB
    readOptions->column_names.reserve( mTable->GetNumberOfColumns() );

    for ( auto & colName : mTable->GetColumnsOrder() )
    {
        readOptions->column_names.emplace_back( colName );
    }

    return readOptions;
}

std::unique_ptr<arrow::csv::ConvertOptions> LoadCSVData::PrepareConvertOptions() const
{
    auto convertOptions = std::make_unique<arrow::csv::ConvertOptions>( arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults() );
    for ( auto & col : mTable->GetColumsInfo() )
    {
        convertOptions->column_types[col.second.GetName()] = MyTypeToArrowDataType( col.second.GetType() );
    }
    convertOptions->strings_can_be_null = true;

    return convertOptions;
}

std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> LoadCSVData::OpenCSVFile( const std::string & filePath )
{
    MTR_SCOPE_FUNC();
    auto inputFileResult = arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open( filePath );
    if ( !inputFileResult.ok() )
    {
        throw BadParametersException( std::string( "CSV file reader error: " ) + inputFileResult.status().ToString() );
    }
    return *inputFileResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maciej, the method `TableReader::Read` should return `shared_ptr<arrow::Table>`.  The `arrow::Table` itself has a number of shared pointers to structures which eventually contain the data.  To free up the data you will need to make sure that the `arrow::Table` and any copies of it are destroyed.  This should happen as soon as that `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.  However, it appears you are storing the table in a member variable here (which is to be expected, you probably want to use the data after you read it):

```
this->mArrowTable = *table;
```

So now you have a second copy of the `arrow::Table` instance.  You could reassign `this->mArrowTable` to a new blank table or you could destroy whatever `this` is.  Of course, if you are making any other copies of the table then you will need to ensure those go out of scope as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It turned out that other part of my code caused the memory leak so that was no Arrow's memory management problem.

Comment: Arrow structures free memory as expected, when `shared_ptr`s are deleted.